# Spark Structured Streaming using sockets, set SCHEMA, Display DATAFRAME in console

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

How can I set a schema for a streaming `DataFrame` in PySpark.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
# Import data types
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")\
    .getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:5560
lines = spark\
   .readStream\
   .format('socket')\
   .option('host', '192.168.0.113')\
   .option('port', 5560)\
   .load()
```

For example I need a table like :

```
Name,  lastName,   PhoneNumber    
Bob, Dylan, 123456    
Jack, Ma, 789456
....
```

How can I set the header/schema to ['Name','lastName','PhoneNumber']
with their data types.

Also, Is it possible to display this table continuously, or say top 20 rows of the `DataFrame`. When I tried it I get the error

> "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;\nProject"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TextSocketSource` doesn't provide any integrated parsing options. It is only possible to use one of the two formats:

- timestamp and text if `includeTimestamp` is set to `true` with the following schema:

  ```py
  StructType([
      StructField("value", StringType()),
      StructField("timestamp", TimestampType())
  ])
  ```
- text only if `includeTimestamp` is set to `false` with the schema as shown below:

  ```py
  StructType([StructField("value", StringType())]))
  ```

If you want to change this format you'll have to transform the stream to extract fields of interest, for example with regular expressions:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract
from functools import partial

fields = partial(
    regexp_extract, str="value", pattern="^(\w*)\s*,\s*(\w*)\s*,\s*([0-9]*)$"
)

lines.select(
    fields(idx=1).alias("name"),
    fields(idx=2).alias("last_name"), 
    fields(idx=3).alias("phone_number")
)
```