# Is there a bug about StructField in SPARK Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

When I try this :

```py
cfg = SparkConf().setAppName('MyApp')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=cfg).getOrCreate()

lines = spark.readStream.load(format='socket', host='localhost', port=9999,
                              schema=StructType(StructField('value', StringType, True)))
words = lines.groupBy('value').count()
query = words.writeStream.format('console').outputMode("complete").start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Then I get some error :

> AssertionError: dataType should be DataType

And I search the source code in ./pyspark/sql/types.py at line 403:

```
assert isinstance(dataType, DataType), "dataType should be DataType"
```

But ***StringType*** based on ***AtomicType*** not ***DataType***

```py
class StringType(AtomicType):
    """String data type.
    """

    __metaclass__ = DataTypeSingleton
```

So is there a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python `DataTypes` are not used as singletons. When creating `StructField` you have have to use an instance. Also `StructType` requires a sequence of `StructField`:

```py
StructType([StructField('value', StringType(), True)])
```

Nevertheless this is completely pointless here. Schema of `TextSocketSource` [is fixed and cannot be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41378447/6910411) with schema argument.