# Give schema in data coming from a tcp socker in spark streaming - JAVA - SPARK

Tags: java, csv, sockets, apache-spark

I have 2 java programs:

- In one java program I have a serversocket waiting from second java program a connection. When a connection arrives, first java program reads a csv and sends it line by line through socket to second java program.
- Second java program is a spark structured streaming.

My question is how can I know csv schema to make operations in spark structured streaming?
Thanks!

**TCP program**:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3434);
Socket socket = ss.accept();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOuputStream()));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(("tmp.csv")));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    writer.write(line);

}
```

**Second JAVA program with Spark Structured Streaming**:

```
SparkSession sp = SparkSession.builder().appName("MyApp").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> line = sp.readStream().format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 3434).load();
```

But ,how can i find schema from line?

```
CSV Schema
----------
Date        Amount   Op
12/10/2018  14       "e43t"
13/10/2019  12       "as30p"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Structured Streaming using sockets, set SCHEMA, Display DATAFRAME in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378447/spark-structured-streaming-using-sockets-set-schema-display-dataframe-in-conso)

Comment: No my friend. I want the line i get from tcp socket to make it a row in a dataframe